# Getting submit button to work for edittext in the recyclerview adapter and main activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am working on a small android app using Java + RecyclerView + CardView

The Recycler View works fine But ...

I want the submit button in the card to get the text from the Edittext field in the same card and assign it to a variable.

I want the listener to be for the button as I have done and not the edittext.

The button works fine if I ask it to do something else, I believe the problem is in retrieving the text from the Edittext in the same card.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks,

My Adapter :

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Exercise> mExerciselist;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onSubClick(int position);//sub button
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public ExerciseAdapter(Context ctx, List<Exercise> exerciselist) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        this.mExerciselist = exerciselist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_card, null); //null is the parent
        return new ExerciseViewHolder(view, mListener);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExerciseViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Exercise exercise = mExerciselist.get(position);


        //bind title and view
        holder.textViewName.setText(exercise.getName());
        holder.textViewWt.setText(exercise.getWt());
        holder.textViewRep.setText(exercise.getRep());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExerciselist.size();
    }

    class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName, textViewWt, textViewRep;
        Button subButton; // Sub button
        EditText wtIn, repIn;
        String wtstr, repstr;

        public ExerciseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exname); //populate card views
            textViewWt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exwt);
            textViewRep = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exrep);
            subButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subex); //sub button
            wtIn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inexwt);
            repIn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inexrep);

            wtstr = wtIn.getText().toString();
            repstr = repIn.getText().toString();

            subButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onSubClick(position);
                        }}
                }
            });

        }
    }


}
```

and the Main Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init views
    mGYMDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gymdaystext);
    inputGYMnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnum);

    //load data
    loadData();


    //populate list
    final ArrayList<Exercise> exerciselist = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));


    //recycle view
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //adapter
    adapter = new ExerciseAdapter(this, exerciselist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //clicking
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExerciseAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSubClick(int position) {

            Exercise exercise = exerciselist.get(position);
            EditText wtIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inexwt);
            EditText repIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inexrep);

            String newwt = wtIn.getText().toString();
            String newrep = repIn.getText().toString();

            exercise.Wt =  newwt ;
            exercise.Rep = newrep;


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

A neater solution would be to pass the two `EditText` strings via the `OnItemClickListener` interface itself. Check the code below, I'm passing the strings via interface and then just using the passed string in `MainActivity` instead of using the `position` to populate the view etc..

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Exercise> mExerciselist;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onSubClick(int position, String wtInText, String repInText);//sub button
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public ExerciseAdapter(Context ctx, List<Exercise> exerciselist) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        this.mExerciselist = exerciselist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_card, null); //null is the parent
        return new ExerciseViewHolder(view, mListener);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExerciseViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Exercise exercise = mExerciselist.get(position);


        //bind title and view
        holder.textViewName.setText(exercise.getName());
        holder.textViewWt.setText(exercise.getWt());
        holder.textViewRep.setText(exercise.getRep());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExerciselist.size();
    }

    class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName, textViewWt, textViewRep;
        Button subButton; // Sub button
        EditText wtIn, repIn;
        String wtstr, repstr;

        public ExerciseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exname); //populate card views
            textViewWt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exwt);
            textViewRep = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exrep);
            subButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subex); //sub button
            wtIn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inexwt);
            repIn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inexrep);

            wtstr = wtIn.getText().toString();
            repstr = repIn.getText().toString();

            subButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onSubClick(position, wtstr , repstr);
                        }}
                }
            });

        }
    }


}
```

Main Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init views
    mGYMDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gymdaystext);
    inputGYMnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnum);

    //load data
    loadData();


    //populate list
    final ArrayList<Exercise> exerciselist = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));
    exerciselist.add(new Exercise("lat","32", "22"));


    //recycle view
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //adapter
    adapter = new ExerciseAdapter(this, exerciselist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //clicking
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExerciseAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSubClick(int position, String wtInText, String repInText) {


            // We get the two Strings here directly without needing to use the position of populate the view and then get the edittext and then get the text....
            exercise.Wt =  wtInText;
            exercise.Rep = repInText;


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```